# How do I iterate through 2 columns of pandas dataframe data?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, iteration, concatenation

I have imported some data and calculated the 5 day, 8 day and 21 day moving averages.

```
             OPEN   HIGH    LOW   LAST     ma5     ma8  ma21
Date                                                        
11/23/2009  88.84  89.19  88.58  88.97     NaN     NaN   NaN
11/24/2009  88.97  89.07  88.36  88.50     NaN     NaN   NaN
11/25/2009  88.50  88.63  87.22  87.35     NaN     NaN   NaN
11/26/2009  87.35  87.48  86.30  86.59     NaN     NaN   NaN
11/27/2009  86.59  87.02  84.83  86.53  87.588     NaN   NaN
11/30/2009  87.17  87.17  85.87  86.41  87.076     NaN   NaN
```

Then I have iterated through the 5 day moving average (ma5) to work out if the average is rising (+1), falling (-1) or constant (0). Using;

```
ma5x = [0,]
lastItem = ma5[0]
for currItem in ma5[1:]:
    if currItem > lastItem: 
        ma5x.append(1)
    elif currItem < lastItem: 
        ma5x.append(-1)
    else:
        ma5x.append(0)
        lastItem = currItem
```

However how do I iterate through 2 columns of data. For instance if I want to see if both the 8 day moving average (ma8) and the 21 day ma (ma21) are both rising together (+1), or both falling together (-1) or if they are moving in different directions (0)?

Secondly how do I then add this data to the original dataframe? I'm not sure how to concat the second dataframe we created above because the original data doesn't have a column index for the first 'Date' column. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `zip` function to iterate through two or more items simultaneously.

```py
ma = []
ma5Last = ma5[0]
ma8Curr = ma8[0]

for ma5Curr, ma8Curr in zip(ma5[1:], ma8[1:]):
    if ma5Curr > ma5Last and ma8Curr > ma8Last:
        ma.append(1)
    elif ma5Curr < ma5Last and ma8Curr < ma8Last:
        ma.append(-1)
    else:
        ma.append(0)
    ma5Last = ma5Curr
    ma8Last = ma8Curr
```

To combine the new dataframe with the original dataframe use `merge`

```py
origData = origData.merge(otherData)
```